# What's Apple's recommendation to use: custom struct or extension?

Tags: ios, swift

What's recommended?

- Option 1: custom struct
- Option 2: extension to a class

This example below is simply a example function that returns a UIColor from the red, green and blue values, without you having to divide the number by 255. The code is written in Swift 5.

For example:

```
struct colorFrom {

    func RGB(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) -> UIColor {

        var red, green, blue, alpha: CGFloat
        red = r / 255
        green = g / 255
        blue = b / 255
        alpha = 1

        var color: UIColor
        color = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)

        return color

    }

}

extension UIColor {

    func RGB(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) -> UIColor {

        var red, green, blue, alpha: CGFloat
        red = r / 255
        green = g / 255
        blue = b / 255
        alpha = 1

        var color: UIColor
        color = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)

        return color

    }

}

colorFrom().RGB(r: 153, g: 153, b: 153)
UIColor().RGB(r: 153, g: 153, b: 153)
```

Comment: In both cases they should be `static` methods, not instance methods.

Comment: In the extension of `UIColor`, you can write a convenience initializer. But you should avoid using `CGFloat` for `r`, `g` and `b`. Usually floating point color components are normalized to 0...1.0. You should better use `Int`, even if you need a little type conversion. Static method can be a second option, but never instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not have any official counsel weighing the difference between these two design choice, AFAIK.

That having been said, a convenience initializer or static method within `UIColor` extension makes perfect sense. But not an instance method, but rather `static` method.

But given that it is customary for RGB values to be represented as values between 0.0 and 1.0, I’d probably make the fact that you’re expecting values between 0 and 255 extremely explicit in both the parameter labels as well as the quick help, e.g.:

```
extension UIColor {
    /// Initializes and returns a color object using the specified RGB component values represented as
    /// values between 0 and 255 (rather than between the customary 0.0 to 1.0).
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - red: Value between 0 and 255.
    ///   - green: value between 0 and 255.
    ///   - blue: Value between 0 and 255.

    convenience init(eightBitRed red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

And then you could do things like:

```
let plum = UIColor(eightBitRed: 148, green: 33, blue: 147)
```

---

A custom `struct` for just this one method (again, it would be a `static` method, if you did do this), probably doesn’t make sense, either. If you had a bunch of methods where some logical grouping within a `struct`, then you might consider it. But on the basis of the information provided, I wouldn’t create a separate struct for this. (And if you were going to create a `struct`, the `struct`’s name should start with an uppercase letter.)